# How do i cut graph in R/ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

In R;

I have the following code:

```
ggsurvplot(curve.histology, conf.int=TRUE, 
legend.labs=legend.histology, surv.scale=c("percent"),risk.table=T, 
ggtheme = theme_bw(), risk.table.fontsize=3.5, xlim=c(0,5), 
ylim=c(0,1), break.time.by=1)
```

There are four variables in "curve.histology". I want all four graphs to stop at x = 5 like my x-axis. Can anyone help with that?

[See graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4K6S.jpg)

```
curve.histology <- 
rs.surv(Surv(time,cens)~ordered(histologi)+ratetable(age = age, sex = 
sex, year = year), ratetable = poptab, method="ederer2")
```

Thanks in advance,

C.

Comment: Can you give a sample of curve.histology? Hard to know whats going on without the data...

Comment: I have added an image in the main text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, setting `xlim` and `expand = 0L` on `coord_cartesian()` may help (as long as arranging the margins by `theme()`). But, I think you should file an issue to the repository of survminer package since editing the ggplot object inside ggsurvplot is a bit painful...

```
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2017-11-12

library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> Loading required package: magrittr
library(survival)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, xlim = c(0, 900), expand = FALSE)

p$plot <- p$plot +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 900), expand = FALSE) +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 20, 5.5, 5.5))
#> Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
p
```

[image: example plot]